# trouble stopping a file read process

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to quit a loop, reading the file contents in to a list, when I hit a the line of text that says "stop". Here is my code:

```
let f_in = "file.text"
let lines = ref [];;

  let chan = open_in f_in in
  try
    while true do

      let line = input_line chan in
      if line = "stop" then raise End_of_file;
      lines := input_line chan :: !lines

    done
  with End_of_file -> close_in chan
```

The problem is that it's reading 1 extra line, and it wont read lines that have the word "stop" within the text. An example would be this kind of file:

```
aaa
bbb stop
ccc stop
ddd
eee
stop
fff
```

Now my code should print all those lines, and stop reading at the line that has the word "stop" alone. Can someone fix this? Thanks.

Comment: You should consider read and comment/accept the answers to questions you've already asked before asking new questions ...

Comment: @Thomas they didn't exactly answer the questions, it wernt any use to me so there's no point in marking a reply as correct if it wasn't what I was asking for :)

Comment: You are behaving in a rude way and making no effort of your own to solve these problems. It's like you're trying to solve a school homework without learning the language at all, only instead of giving us the assignment in one clean shot, you're hashing it in several steps as a way to be rude several times rather than once.

Comment: I am happy to answer OCaml questions (regardless of whether you actually "accept" answers, in fact), but I wish you actually paid a bit of respect to people that give their time for free to help you. Respect goes both ways, and by giving a thorough, detailed answer to one of your questions I've already done my part.

Comment: If people don't answer to your questions as you want, that's maybe because your questions are not sufficiently clear: if you want precise answers, either ask precise questions or comment the answers you get to make your question more precise.

Comment: You are calling input_line twice per loop, but only testing its output once per loop. This would 1) mean that only half the lines are tested for "stop", and 2) cause it to read one more line past a line that managed to be tested successfully for "stop".

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the second `input_line` with `line` yields the result you want.

```
let f_in = "file.text"
let lines = ref [];;

let chan = open_in f_in in
  try
    while true do

      let line = input_line chan in
      if line = "stop" then raise End_of_file;
      lines := !lines @ [ line ]

    done
  with End_of_file -> close_in can
```

The result stored in `lines` is:

```
["aaa"; "bbb stop"; "ccc stop"; "ddd"; "eee"]
```